# MoveFileEx in c:\Program Files (x86) failing with access denied

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a software that is installed in `c:\Program Files (x86)\MyProj`.

It has an updater program that's supposed to replace its `.exe` files when there are newer versions available. It does so by downloading the files with a `.new` suffix into the same folder (`MyProj`), then calls `MoveFileEx()` with `MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING | MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH` to rename the file (replacing the old version). The updater program is linked to a manifest that request elevated privilege (`...<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"/>...`).

On Windows 10, when I run the updater, I get the UAC prompt, then new files get downloaded, but the `MoveFileEx()` call fails with Access Denied.

The same thing happens if I run the updater via the Task Scheduler (run as SYSTEM).

I have checked the folder and file permissions, and SYSTEM has full control to both the `MyProj` folder, and all the files in it.

Any ideas why I would be getting access denied? I have been googling for clues, but I haven't found any situation similar to this.

This used to work in Windows 7, and in early versions of Windows 10 32-bit (a long time ago). It's only recently that I needed to deploy an upgrade and discovered this problem.

I wrote a simple test program that just called the MoveFileEx, and still got the error. The test prog contains the following:

```
#include "framework.h"
#include "test_move.h"

int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    if (!MoveFileEx(
        _T("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MyProj\\test.exe.new"),
        _T("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\MyProj\\test.exe"),
        MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING | MOVEFILE_WRITE_THROUGH))
    {
        _TCHAR msg[80];
        _stprintf_s(msg, _T("Failed with %d"), GetLastError());
        MessageBox(NULL, msg, _T("test_move"), MB_OK);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, _T("Success"), _T("test_move"), MB_OK);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This was created in a new VS2019 project, linked with UAC Execution Level = requireAdministrator, using Multi-Threaded lib (/MT, /MTd).

Comment: The `Program Files` directories are deliberately limited by Windows so that viruses can't modify your existing programs.

Comment: Does the UAC prompt apply to the program that move the file? Does it works by hand (i.e. file moving is not blocked because the target is in use)? If you are able to download the file, then it means that you have write access to the folder.

Comment: @MarkRansom while true in general, admins and the SYSTEM account have access to modify the contents of `Program Files`.

Comment: @mmy I would suggest a slightly different approach.  Download the `.new` file (to a subfolder in the user's profile, like `%APPDATA%\MyProj`, NOT in the `.exe`'s installation folder), and DON'T replace the `.exe` file right away.  When the `.exe` is launched next time, have it detect the `.new` file, and if found then launch the updater with elevated rights and then exit immediately. The updater can then wait for the launching process to exit, then replace the `.exe` with the `.new` file, and then launch the new `.exe` with the user's normal rights.

Comment: @Phil1970 Yes, the UAC prompt applies to the program that moves the file. And no, the target file is not in use when that happens. I can manually delete the target file in file explorer (after UAC prompt) and the updater's MoveFileEx would then work. I changed the updater to try to delete before the move, but that fails with Access Denied as well :-(

Comment: @RemyLebeau Not sure if that's going to help. I wrote a simple test program that just does the MoveFileEx, and that fails with Access Denied as well (after the UAC prompt).

Comment: @mmy Then you are probably doing something wrong, but we can't see what you are doing.  Please show your actual code, or at least a [mcve].

Comment: @RemyLebeau I've edited my original post and added my sample code. My original code is compiled in VS2005 (that's how old that code is!). To rule out the compiler, I re-created my test program in VS2019, but still get the Access Denied error :-(

Comment: Found a clue. If I manually create the MyProj folder, and manually copy the files there, the test_move program succeeds. If the MyProj folder is created by the original installer, it fails. I compared the security on the 2 folders, and they are identical. The only difference was ownership: the manual one was owned by administrators, the installer one by SYSTEM. However, changing the installer one to administrators did not fix the problem :-( Still digging ...

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really explain what happened, but rebooting the PC seems to have fixed the problem. So I guess that, somehow, the file was locked, or in use, but I swear it wasn't listed in the Task Manager. Anyway, apologies for wasting everybody's time.